# How to improve Time to Interactive when loading GTM scripts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager

I am trying to include GTM tags in js website and able to do it but then it decreases the Time to Interactive (TTI) of the website.
Also tried to use `async` and `defer` tags for script loading but it won't help.
TTI goes down to 8s.
The effect is mostly on the mobile Lighthouse performance. Desktop is fine.

How can I improve on mobile TTI while loading GTM scripts?

Comment: TTI change due to GTM load makes very little sense. Nothing in DOM is supposed to be depending on GTM. If it's loaded asyncly (which it should), it's not supposed to delay anything. Never have I had issues with GTM delaying stuff except rare cases when a GTM container contains too much obscure logic that would just brutally load the client machine. I would suggest testing TTI with an empty container and if you still see significant TTI impact, then your measuring procedure is seriously off.

Comment: Have tested this, still seeing this issue..

Comment: Tested in multiple places.... lighthouse....pagespeed etc

Comment: Where you have used it?

Comment: well if TTI really goes down by seconds, then you should be able to see the difference manually, shouldn't you? Do you actually see the difference with TTI when you load a page with GTM vs without it?

Comment: Yes, able to see the difference with or without it

Comment: The difference is only on the numbers of TTI. Website is loading perfectly...no issues

Comment: Well, then don't pay attention to it! Unless you want to debug the Lighthouse's algo that measures TTI. I would tell the same to SEOs. The issue with SEOs is that they often take vanity metrics and use them as if they know how they were measured. GTM is basically a world standard for low-budget tracking.